# Remove items one at a time using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a to-do list using HTML/CSS, Javascript and JQuery. The problem I have occurs when I try to delete an item off the list. Here is the Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
            if($('#input').val() != '')
                $('.container').append('<p class="todo">'+$('#input').val()+'</p><span class="del">&times</span><br/>');
        });

      $(document).on('click','.del',function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.todo').hide(); 
        });
      });
    });
```

The HTML

```
<body>
    <h1 class="header">To-Do List</h1>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
```

What the above does is it removes all of the dynamically generated todo [paragraph] elements when a single del element [an x] is clicked. I am asking how to change the code so clicking the del element removes the todo element that it was generated with. I understand I can use ids but I feel that is too cumbersome. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to hide only the immediate previous sibling `.todo` paragraph of clicked `.del`:

```
$('.container').on('click','.del',function(){
    $(this).prev().hide(); 
});
```

Also take note that you don't need to use `.click()` event for `.del` any more since you've already using event delegation to attach the click event to them as well as using closest static parent for delegated event instead of `$(document)`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `prev()` ? `.del` is not in `.todo`

Comment: Yeah it'll be easier if OP wraps every line in a `div` or something slimier, because now the `.del` button will still be there. Also `.remove` should be a better option imo

Answer (score 1):

Try this `jQuery`, this also hides the 'x':

```
          $(document).on('click','.del',function(){
                $(this).hide(); 
                $(this).prev().hide();
          });
```